# 'Movie materials' doesn't play in Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine

So, I'm trying to play an MP4 on a big plane in Eevee, but it doesn't work. It does work in Cycles, but I can't render a 4400 frame animation in Cycles. When in Eevee, the MP4 won't play and the only way to see a frame from it is to jump to that frame in Cycles, pre-render that and go back to Eevee. Is there anything I can do to make it work in Eevee as well?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I think you might just have to wait until support for this comes out. Sorry.

Comment: What about Workbench engine? I haven't tried it before, but you have a chance to unwrap it here! If it don't work then wait if some knows the better answer or as @RixYarbrough said wait till the feature comes in Blender.